# Uninitialized variables

Tags: c, function, variables

I am trying to write two functions, one that takes input the other calculates acceleration. The compiler is telling me that my variables are uninitialized but they should have values from the input. What am I doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_instructions(double vi, double vf);
double compute_acceleration(double vi, double vf);

int main()
{
    double vi;
    double vf;
    double acc;
    double t;


    input_instructions(vi, vf);

    acc = compute_acceleration(vi,vf);

    t = (vf - vi)/acc;

    printf("The constant acceleration of the cyclist is %.2f and it will take him %.2f minutes/seconds/"
            "to come to rest with an initial velocity of 10mi/hr.\n", acc, t);
}

void input_instructions(double vi, double vf)
{
    printf("This program will calculate the rate of accleration and the time it takes/"
            "the cyclist to come to rest\n");
    printf("Enter inital velocity=>");
    scanf("%lf", &vi);
    printf("Enter final velocity");
    scanf("%lf", &vf);
}

double compute_acceleration(double vi, double vf)
{
    double t = 1;
    double a = (vf-vi)/t;
    return (a);
}
```

Comment: That's not how functions work in C. Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1006/function-parameters

Comment: You seem a bit clueless. What part of the C class are you at? Do you know what a pointer and pass by reference is?

Comment: I am clueless. We haven't learned about pass by's and pointers yet.

Comment: What needs to be fixed?

Comment: C is strictly pass-by-value!

Answer (score 3):

Wow,  a lot of bad stuff going on here.  Other than the uninitialized variables declared in main() (yes, the compiler is correct) C passes parameters by-value.  vi and vf parameters *values* are stored on the stack.  Your scanf then takes the address of that stack variable, assigns a value to it, the function returns, and the assigned values are gone - poof!

```
void input_instructions(double vi, double vf)
{
    printf("Enter inital velocity=>");
    scanf("%lf", &vi);
    printf("Enter final velocity");
    scanf("%lf", &vf);

    // function returns and input parameter values are gone.
 }
```

You want to pass in the pointer to your variables, like this:

```
void input_instructions(double *vi, double *vf)
    {
        printf("This program will calculate the rate of accleration and the time it takes/"
                "the cyclist to come to rest\n");
        printf("Enter inital velocity=>");
        scanf("%lf", vi);
        printf("Enter final velocity");
        scanf("%lf", vf);
```

and call from main() like this:

```
   input_instructions(&vi, &vf);
```

See [examples](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-function-parameter-passing/) .

Comment: It won't let me do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading in the variables in your input_instructions function so they can't be "passed in". And since their memory is spun up inside the function, they are not accessible outside of it.

One option for you is to change the variables vi and vf to global variables by declaring them outside of main,  do not bother having them in the signature of input_functions, and the rest will likely be fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Prototypes */
void input_instructions();
double compute_acceleration(double new_vi, double new_vf);

/* Globals */
double vi;
double vf;

int main()
{
```

In this case, since you're passing globals around, you wouldn't even necessarily need to accept parameters on the compute_acceleration function either. I don't usually recommend globals but that seems to be the least of the issues you are dealing with.

Another option is to initialize the variables vi and vf in main to 0, and then pass them by reference into the input_instructions so that their value can be changed by the function.

for example:

```
 void input_instructions(double *i, double *f);
 double compute_acceleration(double x, double y);


 int main()
 {
     double vi = 0;
     double vf = 0;
     double acc = 0;
     double t = 0;


     input_instructions(&vi, &vf);
     acc = compute_acceleration(vi,vf);
```

I've change the name of the variables to help understand where the memory locations of variables exist and show how in your example, vi in main is actually a different variable than vi inside the called methods.

Comment: How do I make the variables of the two functions local to each other in the main function?

Comment: Functions spin up their own variables that only they can use on the stack. They are not available to any other function and as soon as the function ends, they are cleaned up from the stack. Functions called by main don't even have access to the variables from main. The first solution I gave uses global, not local variables. Global variables are created on the heap, not the stack so they they are accessible across the solution.

Comment: The second solution uses pass by reference. New variables are still spun up inside the functions called by main, but they pass into them (through the parameters) the memory locations on the stack for the values in main.This enable you to make changes that affect parts of the stack you don't normally have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Declare vi,vf,acc and t as global variables (outside the main).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_instructions();
double compute_acceleration();
double vi;
double vf;
double acc;
double t;
int main()
{



    input_instructions();

    acc = compute_acceleration();

    t = (vf - vi)/acc;

    printf("The constant acceleration of the cyclist is %.2f and it will take him %.2f minutes/seconds/"
            "to come to rest with an initial velocity of 10mi/hr.\n", acc, t);
}

void input_instructions()
{
    printf("This program will calculate the rate of accleration and the time it takes/"
            "the cyclist to come to rest\n");
    printf("Enter inital velocity=>");
    scanf("%lf", &vi);
    printf("Enter final velocity");
    scanf("%lf", &vf);
}

double compute_acceleration()
{
    double t = 1;
    double a = (vf-vi)/t;
    return (a);
}
```

Or you can use pointers and pass them to 'input_instructions' function.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. I suspect the global variable solution is the one the professor was looking for in this case since he indicated they haven't covered pass by reference yet.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
void input_instructions(double vi, double vf)
{
.
.
}
```

The variables `vi` are `vf` are local to the function and have no bearing on similarly named variables in the `main()` function. In other words they have `function-scope` and they cease to exist after the function returns.

What you should've been doing is :

```
input_instructions(&vi,&vf); // pass the address in the main()
```

and rewrite the function as :

```
void input_instructions(double *vi, double *vf) // Using pointers
{
    printf("This program will calculate the rate of accleration and the time it takes/"
            "the cyclist to come to rest\n");
    printf("Enter inital velocity=>");
    scanf("%lf", vi); // Hmm, you're changing the value in the main()
    printf("Enter final velocity");
    scanf("%lf", vf); // Note no '&' since we're dealing with pointers.
}
```

Here persistent changes are made to `main()`'s `vf` and `vi` using the the formal arguments `*vf` and `*vi` of the function `input_instructions`.